# Mapping a json object into a Java map

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I'm consuming an API that returns a JSON object and I want to convert it to a Java map without using a library. This is the payload I want to convert:

```json
{
    "customerId": "23408068569991",
    "data": [
        {
            "nodeId": "HTS",
            "subscriptionId": "P_HTS_Video_1072",
            "subscriptionName": "HTS_Video_1053",
            "subscriptionDescription": "P_HTS_Video_1072",
            "amountCharged": 0.0,
            "statusCode": "0000",
            "adjustmentType": null,
            "startDate": "2021-09-28 07:41:29",
            "endDate": "2021-10-18 07:29:40"
        }
    ],
    "links": [],
    "statusCode": "0000",
    "statusMessage": "0 Success.",
    "transactionId": "12677889909988"
}
```

to the format below:

```json
{
  "customerId": "string",
  "transactionId": "string",
  "statusMessage": "string",
  "supportMessage": "string",
  "services": {
    "vas_hlr": {
      "statusCode": "2000",
      "data": [
        {
          "subscriptionId": "P_HTS_Video_1072",
          "subscriptionProviderId": "HTC",
          "subscriptionName": "CHTS_Video_1053",
          "subscriptionDescription": "P_HTS_Video_1072",
          "subscriptionStatus": "Inactive",
          "subscriptionType": "Adhoc",
          "subscriptionLength": null,
          "registrationChannel": null,
          "startDate": "2019-04-30",
          "endDate": "2019-05-06",
          "subscriptionPaymentSource": "Airtime",
          "amountCharged": 50,
          "sendSMSNotification": true,
          "beneficiaryId": null,
          "auto-renew": true,
          "email": null,
          "partnerId": "String",
          "partnerName": "String",
          "lastDeductionChargeDate": "String"
        }
      ]
    },
    
  }
}
```

So this is what I have tried out but not working:

```
public class ComvivaCustomerSubscriptions extends APIResponse {
    private String customerId;
    private String statusMessage;
    private String transactionId;
    private String supportMessage;
    private Map<String, SubscriptionService> services;
    private APIError apiError;

    public void joinServices(SubscriptionService customerSubscriptions) {
        if (customerSubscriptions == null || null == customerSubscriptions.getData()) {
            return;
        }
        String theCustomerId = customerSubscriptions.getCustomerId();
        if (theCustomerId != null && this.customerId == null) {
            this.setCustomerId(theCustomerId);
        }
        String statusMessage = customerSubscriptions.getStatusMessage();
        if (statusMessage != null && this.statusMessage == null) {
            this.setStatusMessage(statusMessage);
        }
        setTransactionId(customerSubscriptions.getTransactionId());
        setSupportMessage(customerSubscriptions.getSupportMessage());
        Map<String, SubscriptionService> serviceMap = (Map<String, SubscriptionService>) 
        customerSubscriptions.getData();
        if (serviceMap == null) {
            return;
        }

        if (this.services == null) {
            this.services = serviceMap;
            return;
        }
        this.services.putAll(serviceMap);
    }
}
```

Comment: How is it not working? What is expected, and what is actual output?

Comment: Define "without a library". IN my book that is parse the result myself (the inputstream, into a string and do some string munging to get the result I want).

Comment: I'm getting null after calling this joinServices method on the instance of ComvivaCustomerSubscriptions and passing the JSON object as a parameter. The output I'm expecting to get is the second son payload I posted above o the page. What I mean by not using a library is that I mean not using Gson and the likes.

Comment: If you want to do that without a library then you have to write a json parser yourself and from scratch. I don't know why you want to do that but it's complicated and need much effort and it's beyond an answer here.